# Почему не срабатывает функция JS

Tags: javascript

У меня в коде 2 функциональные кнопки `add` - которая должна добавить обьект в массив и `show`, которая должна добавить все элементы из массива в таблицу. Вроде все сделал, но не работает.

** Вот код : **

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Main

```
<script>

    var myCarArray = [];

    function addCar() {
        var name = document.getElementById("inputName");
        var price = document.getElementById("inputPrice");
        var image = document.getElementById("inputImage");

        myCarArray.push(new Car(name, price, image));
    }
    function showCar() {
        console.log("Name is : ");

        addRow();
    }
    function addRow() {
        for (var x = 0; x < myCarArray.length; x++) {
            var theTable = document.getElementById("showCars");
            var row = theTable.insertRow(-1);
            var name = row.insertCell(0);
            name.innerHTML = myCarArray[x].getName();
            var price = row.insertCell(1);
            price.innerHTML = myCarArray[x].getPrice();
            var image = row.insertCell(2);
            image.innerHTML = myCarArray[x].getImage();
        }
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>

<table border="10">
<tr>
    <th>name</th>
    <th>price</th>
    <th>image</th>
</tr>

<tr>
    <th><input id="inputName"></th>
    <th><input id="inputPrice"></th>
    <th><input id="inputImage"></th>
</tr>
</table>

<button onclick="addCar">add</button>
<button onclick="showCar">show</button>

<table border="10" id="showCars">
<tr>
    <th>name</th>
    <th>price</th>
    <th>image</th>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

** и вот класс : **

```
function Car(theName, thePrice, theImage) {
this.name = theName;
this.price = thePrice;
this.image = theImage;
}
Car.prototype.showMe = function () {
console.log("Name is : " + this.name + " price is : " + this.price + " image : " + this.image);
};
Car.prototype.getName = function () {
return this.name;
};
Car.prototype.getPrice = function () {
return this.price;
};
Car.prototype.getImage = function () {
return this.image;
};
```

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: а есть какие ошибки в консоле? и вообще, что именно не работает?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Вот так у меня заработало все:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Main</title>

<script src="Car.js"></script>
<script>
    var myCarArray = [];
    function addCar() {
        var name = document.getElementById("inputName").value;
        var price = document.getElementById("inputPrice").value;
        var image = document.getElementById("inputImage").value;

        myCarArray.push(new Car(name, price, image));
    }
    function showCar() {
        var theTable = document.getElementById("showCars");
        for (var x = 0; x < myCarArray.length; x++) {
            myCarArray[x].showMe(theTable);
        }
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>

<table border="10">
<tr>
    <th>name</th>
    <th>price</th>
    <th>image</th>
</tr>

<tr>
    <th><input id="inputName"></th>
    <th><input id="inputPrice"></th>
    <th><input id="inputImage"></th>
</tr>
</table>

<button onclick="addCar()">add</button>
<button onclick="showCar()">show</button>

<table border="10" id="showCars">
<tr>
    <th>name</th>
    <th>price</th>
    <th>image</th>
</tr>
</table>
</body> 
</html>
```

**и вот класс**

```
function Car(theName, thePrice, theImage) {
this.name = theName;
this.price = thePrice;
this.image = theImage;
}
Car.prototype.showMe = function (table) {
var row = table.insertRow(-1);
var name = row.insertCell(0);
name.innerHTML = this.name;
var price = row.insertCell(1);
price.innerHTML = this.price;
var image = row.insertCell(2);
image.innerHTML = "<img width= '100' src='this.image'/>";
};
```

Answer (score 0):

основное: не было значений в функции addCar и запуска () в кнопке add

```js
var myCarArray = [];

function addCar() {
  var name = document.getElementById("inputName").value;
  var price = document.getElementById("inputPrice").value;
  var image = document.getElementById("inputImage").value;
  myCarArray.push(new Car(name, price, image));
  addRow()
}

function addRow() {
  var car = myCarArray.slice(-1)[0];
  if (!car) return;
  var theTable = document.getElementById("showCars");
  var row = theTable.insertRow(-1);
  var name = row.insertCell(0);
  name.innerHTML = car.getName();
  var price = row.insertCell(1);
  price.innerHTML = car.getPrice();
  var image = row.insertCell(2);
  image.innerHTML = car.getImage()
}

function Car(theName, thePrice, theImage) {
  this.name = theName;
  this.price = thePrice;
  this.image = theImage
}
Car.prototype.showMe = function() {
  console.log("Name is : " + this.name + " price is : " + this.price + " image : " + this.image)
};
Car.prototype.getName = function() {
  return this.name
};
Car.prototype.getPrice = function() {
  return this.price
};
Car.prototype.getImage = function() {
  return this.image
};
```

```html
<table border="10">
  <tr>
    <th>name</th>
    <th>price</th>
    <th>image</th>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <th>
      <input id="inputName">
    </th>
    <th>
      <input id="inputPrice">
    </th>
    <th>
      <input id="inputImage">
    </th>
  </tr>
</table>

<button onclick="addCar()">add</button>


<table border="10" id="showCars">
  <tr>
    <th>name</th>
    <th>price</th>
    <th>image</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```